# firefox 15 not saving canvas in html when using save as webpage

Tags: firefox, canvas

I wanted to save a webpage in which there are pie charts generated using canvas.

When i opened the saved file i could not find the pie chart.

How to enable firefox to include canvas in the output?

Chrome is doing well with respect to this. but i can use only firefox.

suggestion please

Comment: Perhaps if you post the URL we can look at the source and see what's going on. It could be that some JavaScript is not being rendered because FF is saving relative URL's (which go nowhere when you load them locally). Perhaps Chrome is smart enough to render the fully qualified path, or maybe even save them locally?

Comment: i am using yslow plugin and it opens the reports in a new tab without any url or we can see only the source and cannot open the same report in another tab because as i said it is dynamically generated